# How to make an ipa file?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I create a ipa file for my iOS application?

I have written the complete code for my iPhone app and now I'd like to make .ipa file.

Answer (score 28):

- Within XCode choose Build > Build & Archive.
- In your XCode Organizer (Window > Organizer), you'll see your archived apps
- Select one, hit 'Share...' and 'Save to Disk'

Comment: "Build & Archive" is disabled in my Xcode.  Oh, wait.  Was in simulator.  Have to change to "device"

Comment: In XCode 4, in the upper left corner you have field with your project and target device. Line this: `Test_01 >> iPhone 5.0 Simulator`. Those are actually two drop down menus on which you can click to reveal additional options.

Answer (score 24):

The one suggested by @heinklein is the easiest way but another option is to do the following.

> 1. Add necessary profiles and adjust build settings.
> 2. Set device as target to run the application.
> 3. Build the product.
> 4. Go to Products->yourAppName.app. Right click and show in finder.
> 5. Drag & drop to itunes profile and binary file.
> 6. Select app in iTunes and right click to show in Finder. And there you can get the .ipa file.

Comment: This is the best way to go if you don't want Apple mess up with your custom provisioning profiles. By default, Apple creates a new distribution profile and use that for your app if you want to export an archive for testing purposes. This worked for me to test notifications. Couldn't found any other way yet!

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes it may happen that Xcode Archiver fails to generate ipa file. Then here is the another option.

1. Build the application.
2. After successful build go to "Products" folder in your project navigator.
3. Right click on it and go to "Show in Finder".
4. Copy the .app file.
5. Create a new folder at some other location lets say on Desktop with name "Payload".
6. Paste that .app file in Payload folder.
7. Zip the Payload folder.
8. Rename that zipped folder with .ipa

Thats it.

Reverse procedure is used to retrieve the app file from an ipa file.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I wish i could add +1000 up vote for you
my problem solved after one week.
very very thanks ;)

Answer (score 7):

Stepwise Procedure to create an IPA file,

1.First of all,choose your device as **IOS Device** in **Scheme** near Breakpoint tab in Xcode.

2.In Xcode menu,Product->Clean and build your application.

3.If the provisioning certificate is not valid,it will lead to build failed with an error.If so you have to change it to a valid certificate through your project->build settings.Else if build succeeded just leave this step.

4.Then select Product->archive,it will create an archive file in Organiser->archives and open it up for you after archive finished.

5.choose **share**  tab in Organiser followed by contents->.ipa and Identity->choose your valid distribution certificate and click **next**.

6.within a minute it will ask name for your IPA file to save.Give a name and save it in Desktop.

7.Open iTunes and drag and drop your IPA file in Library->Apps.

8.Now connect and select your Device in itunes->choose apps tab under it and sync your app ipa to the Device.It will install your IPA file to the device.

9.Thats all.Now you can run your App IPA file in your device.

Answer (score 6):

**Using Archive process with Xcode 9.0**

1. Clean your project from `Product` -> `Clean` (`cmd + shift + k`)
2. Select `Product` -> `Archive`

[image: Step1 and 2]

3. Once archive is successfully completed it will open in `Organizer window`
4. Press `Export` button present on right side

[image: Step 3 and 4]

5. Now select the distribution method as per your need and click on `Next` button

[image: Step 5]

6. This will show the App Store distribution options. Now click on `Next` button

[image: Step 6]

7. Re-sign your project (preferred is `Automatically manage signing`) and click on `Next` button

[image: Step 7]

8. There will be Review window containing IPA content details. Click on `Export`.

[image: Step 8]

9. Now choose the location where folder is to be saved and Click on `Export`.

[image: Step 9]

10. This will create an folder containing `IPA`, packaging.log, DistributionSummary.plist and ExportOptions.plist file

[image: Step 10]

Answer (score 5):

As of Xcode 4.3, there is no option of Share in organizer. You need to select distribute and then select the option for save as enterprise or adhoc application.

Answer (score 4):

1. First complete your coding check it with your provisioning profile.
2. Then click to run on device or ipad.
3. then go to menu -> prodcut -> clean.
4. After cleaning  menu -> product -> Archive .
5. After completing it click on share  and click on next button.
6. It will take a minute as per your app file size.
7. then give a name of ipa and save it where you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using xCode 7.2 and have just exported an <s>.api</s> .ipa file to upload to Diawi to share the app with my friends. So here is how I did it:

- Product -> Archive
- After a while, the Organizer would show up -> Export
- Choose something with Ad-hoc, xCode would generate a folder with the .api file in your desktop

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps someone: if you are kicked  out of organiser this is how to re-open it. From there you can compile ipa file as recommended. AD Hoc is for sharing ipa by email and you need to archive for "Generic iOS device".

[image]