# iPhone App Ad-hoc testing

Tags: xcode, testing

So I am currently making an app for somebody else that lives in another state. Is there any way that I can somehow upload it (Ad-hoc?) to somewhere, and they can download it on their phone to test out themselves? I'm guessing I would have to know there ID's for their iPhone.

If this is possible, how can I do this? I currently have the $99 developer license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open http://www.diawi.com

Now drag and drop your project's .ipa file and your provisioning profile.

After click on send button one LINK is created

Now you can send this link to somewhere and he/she can download your application.

hope it will help you.

Comment: Phil Scarf : Hope my ans will help you.

Answer (score 0):

@Phil Scarf,

Create a Ad-hoc distribution certificate and add devices to that(using their device uuid's).  Compile Xcode project using created distribution certificate. create .ipa file and send distribution certificate and .ipa file. Using both, they can install.

Below links may help you:

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711586/how-to-make-an-ipa-file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some sites which gives the facility to upload the .ipa file and then  returns a URL to your application and this will not be publicly visible . you just need to share this URL with your client and make sure , that the .ipa file for your app has been signed for the client device other vise it will not install on his device.

site are :- http://www.diawi.com/
              https://testflightapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can provide them with test build.That is the purpose of adhoc-distribution.

You can provide build in many number of ways. .api file is the output file that you know.Jus run the code copy the api and you can share it

When creating the provision profile we add the list of devices to be tested so add the client `udid` there and download and install the new profile

and from the developer portal create a adhoc distribution certificate

The best way is to distribute [over the air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota)