# IOS - Publishing application without source

Tags: ios, publishing

I have a company that want to buy my IOS application. 
I will publish application through theirs developing account, but I don't want to give them the application source.

So can I give them just app file and then they publish it? Something like app.exe (win) file?

I never publish app. before but I need quick answer before I read all publishing documentation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can give only app file(IPA file). So there is no need to give source code.you have to follow this step : 
[How to make an ipa file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711586/how-to-make-an-ipa-file)