# Making an iOS app of my Ionic AngularJS program

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I made a build for Android, I just ran ionic build and it created an apk file where I was able to download from an Android mobile phone.

I'm now trying to make an IOS build. However, when I ran ionic build, it created a directory called mytabs.app. I want to see the app on my Iphone 6. How is it done?

Comment: are you using macbook to build for IOS?

Comment: Yup, I'm on Mac OSX laptop. OSX Yosemite 10.10.4 version. It's my first time trying ionic. I've also don't know the process how an app is installed on iphones. 4 years ago at previous job sent me a file what i was able to install on my son's iphone 4. It didn't use the Mac Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a detailed series of posts for Pluralsight which outline the exact process of how this is done. You can take a look at the tutorials [over at Pluralsight](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/review/how-to-polish-create-icons-and-splash-screen-images-add-ads-share-and-test-our-calculator-application/article.md) - the third one (the fourth one is [here](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/review/how-to-publish-our-calculator-application-to-the-apple-s-app-store-and-google-s-play-store/article.md)). The section you'll be most likely interested in is titled `How to test our application on the real physical devices and emulators`).

If you're interested to learn a bit more about Ionic framework from start to publishing the app in the stores you can take a look at the ebook I made from 4 posts I wrote for Pluralsight (totaling over 20k+ words): https://leanpub.com/ionic-framework. *You can get the book for free if you want, just enter 0 as amount.*

The process is rather too long to explain in detail here, so I urge you to take a look at the links I provided. However, for reference steps you should take are:

- Get Apple developer license
- Install Xcode
- Create a build file with `ionic build ios`
- Open up the generated project with Xcode
- Connect your phone (or use the simulator)
- Run your app on phone (or simulator)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. I'll check it out. My app is already running in the IOS simulator but wanted to see the app in real life on an iphone hardware :) I'll try it tonight once I get home. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, you'll need to get yourself an Apple developer license even if you just want to run the app on your actual device. It's a bit weird, I agree, but hey that's how Apple has it :)

Comment: Just got home. So how did my officemate create the file? When I installed it, I remember not going to the Apple store on the phone. I'm going to search for the email and find out the extension of the file. I hope I'll find it.

Comment: I found the email and the attached file. The file extension is .ipa I searched what ipa means and found out it means - iOS App Store Package. I don't know how he created the .ipa file though.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26550/what-does-ipa-stand-for

Comment: Ok Nikola, I read your pluralsight tutorial. That's an awesome tutorial! Tons of great information. If you saw my comment before this one, my officemate sent me an .ipa file to my yahoo account. Do you know how he made the .ipa file?

Comment: I'm glad you found the tutorials useful. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711586/how-to-make-an-ipa-file) may help with your .ipa question.

Comment: Nikola, I'm signing up for the Apple Developer program. I'm about to complete the form. However, Apple is charging $99 for it. Is this correct?  http://imgur.com/RTOaSMD

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Even more so, they're charging it every year. Compared to Google Play Store where you pay a one time fee of 25$.

Comment: if I was able to show the sample ionic app using the android simulator, I would have went that route. Unfortunately, the app won't show up. Using "ionic emulate ios", it was a breeze and very quick.

Comment: Here is what I'm thinking and maybe it will work. Even if the app doesn't show in the android emulator, I will copy the apk file to my web server and then download this file from my download and run it. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: You can do that for Android devices without a problem. Just build an .apk file, copy it to your phone (or via webserver as you mentioned) and you're done. You can find the details to do this in the tutorials I mentioned. Good luck!

Comment: It worked! I installed it on my Samsung Note 3. Still shocked that I didn't have to changed any AngularJS code and it worked on Android. :) So looks like I can write any AngularJS code using Ionic and it will work on IOS and Android and I think Windows using WP8

Comment: Yes, that's what hybrid applications are all about :). Same source code for all platforms. And the best of all, if you're a web developer you already know how to use these tools.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need a Apple developer account. And a Mac book with xcode and ios sdk installed on it. Check out cordova site to know which versions of xcode and ios sdk is required.

Then you need to

1. generate a private key,
2. create a certificate signing request (a .csr file) using your private key.
3. Upload this .csr file in your developer account. Now you will get an option to download your developer certificate. Download and save it to your local drive.
4. Create PEM file
5. Create provision file
6. Now build your app by using certificate you got from developers account and provision file

This will give you your .ipa file.

P.S. while creating provision file you need to mention unique id of device on which you are going to install it.

Also check this link for more details http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows

Comment: I think I have a developer account because sometimes when I download a program from apple.com, I get a popup window to enter my username/password. It's also the account I used to download xcode before. I have xcode installed but I'm not sure if I installed ios sdk on this laptop. I have cordova installed and it's running. I am able to run cordova tool. However, I'm very sure I have not done starting step 1. I'll do it now and let you know when I hit a wall.

Comment: I have Xcode installed. Would it mean that I also have IOS sdk installed?

Comment: Yes, if you had chosen to install ios sdk while installing xcode, otherwise NO.

Comment: Ok. I ran xcode and clicked Preferences->Downloads and this is what I am seeing. http://i.imgur.com/zTbyIKf.jpg