# How to upload an ios application to the Internet without putting it in the AppStore?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to upload an ios application to the Internet without putting it in the AppStore so that you can download it on iphone using the link?

Comment: You can't. Period.

Comment: There are apps like TestFlight that let you distribute beta versions of apps, and Apple's Enterprise program allows companies to set up "private app stores" for use within the company. It's not possible to distribute apps to just anybody unless the person doing the downloading us using a Jailbroken phone.

Comment: You can eventually use Ad-Hoc distribution but need the user device id

Comment: You can crate an ipa and upload it and before that you have to add the device UUId to developer console. You can follow below link to create ipa.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711586/how-to-make-an-ipa-file

Answer (score 1):

You can Upload it to testfairy or with ad-hoc testing you can upload it on diawi or installinair, or apphost and generate a link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).